# Do any of the regex syntaxes in the standard library support (?(DEFINE) for subpattern referencing?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, subroutine

With PCRE you can define subpatterns which can be referenced later on. Here's a trivial example:

```
# start delimiter
/

# define non-matching subpatterns, is this supported by <regex>?
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<alpha> [A-Za-z])
  (?<num> [0-9])
)

# actual pattern, referencing subpattern definitions
^ (?&alpha){2} (?&num){2} $

#end delimiter and extended flag to ignore whitespace in pattern
/x
```

Do any of the regex syntaxes from the standard library `<regex>` support this, or is this really a PCRE-specific feature, perhaps?

I'm working with C++11.

Comment: You can see all supported syntax's here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. I've seen this, but I don't know enough about all those syntaxes to know whether they support it. A reasonably thorough search yielded no results either, so far. That's probably a good indicator. But, coming from a PHP background, as PHP supports PCRE, yet doesn't mention this syntax in its own documentation either, I thought perhaps this could be a feature, that's somehow supported, but undocumented.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a solid documentation on PCRE and I think community shouldn't work on it either. It's just enough to know which regex flavor is being used in a language or environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<regex>` library supports the following grammars:

- `ECMAScript`:    The [Modified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) ECMAScript regular expression grammar;
- `basic`:     The [basic POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) regular expression grammar;
- `extended`:  The [extended POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) regular expression grammar;
- `awk`:   The regular expression grammar used by the [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04) utility in
  POSIX;
- `grep`:  The regular expression grammar used by the grep utility in
  POSIX. This is effectively the same as the basic option with the
  addition of newline '\n' as an alternation separator;
- `egrep`:     The regular expression grammar used by the grep utility,
  with the -E option, in POSIX. This is effectively the same as the
  extended option with the addition of newline '\n' as an alternation
  separator in addtion to '|'.

Unfortunately, none of them support this feature.

More information on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type).